# Help with Error generated creating Token. I posted a screenshot of error

Tags: tokens

I took a screenshot of the error that was generated.  Someone please help me resolve this.  Thank you.

[image: The image shows the error in written form]

Code:
1 pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
2
3 import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-
4 contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

5 contract MEEBA is ERC20 {
6    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public     ERC20 ("MEEBA", "MEEBA"){
7        _mint(msg.sender,initialSupply);
8    }
9 }

Answer (score 0):

> I took a screenshot of the error that was generated.

That's not an error, it's a *warning*.

This means your contract has successfully compiled. You can either leave the warning there and ignore it, or fix it.

To fix it - according to the warning message - you need to remove the `public` [visibility specifier](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/cheatsheet.html?highlight=visibility#function-visibility-specifiers). As of Solidity 0.7.0, [these are no longer required for constructors](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.5/070-breaking-changes.html#functions-and-events):

> Visibility (public / external) is not needed for constructors anymore:
> To prevent a contract from being created, it can be marked abstract.
> This makes the visibility concept for constructors obsolete.