# Using remix and cannot get this to compile. please help

Tags: remix, bsc

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
    
    import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
    
    contract y is ERC20  {
        constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20("y", "y") {
            _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply); 
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Please, put some effort before submitting a question! Format the source code in the question. Say something about the problem don't dumpt your code and expect someone to fix it. What did you try? What's the error? What are you trying to achieve? Are you following some tutorial?

Comment: It does compile, with two warnings.

Comment: It's a duplicate of this, but I can't flag because that one has no upvoted/accepted answer -> https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99178/help-with-error-generated-creating-token-i-posted-a-screenshot-of-error/99184#99184

Answer (score 0):

Just to echo Ismael's comment, if you had searched for the warning message using the search bar at the top of the site, you could have solved your problem with very little effort.

Here's the same question that I answered yesterday: [Help with Error generated creating Token. I posted a screenshot of error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99178/help-with-error-generated-creating-token-i-posted-a-screenshot-of-error/99184#99184)

---

Your code compiles without any errors.

It has 2 *warnings*, which can be ignored if you wish. The code has still compiled.

This is the main warning:

> Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the
> contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient. -->
> bar.sol:6:5: | 6 | constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public
> ERC20("y", "y") { | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans
> across multiple lines).

See the previous question I've linked to above for the answer. I'll flag your question for duplication...